# Searching for a vector in a list

Tags: r, list, search, vector

This might seem like a silly question, but after spending some time looking for an (easy) solution, I could not find it.

I have a list of vectors:

```
l <- list(c(1, 2), c(5, 10))
```

and I want to test whether a given vector --- for instance, `c(1, 2)` --- is in that list. I thought the "straightforward" approach would work:

```
c(1, 2) %in% l
```

but that returns

```
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

In the end I found the following solution:

```
any(sapply(l, function(x) { all(x == c(1, 2)) }))
```

but it is quite cumbersome, so I really wonder if that is the simplest option. Is there any simpler way to test for a vector in a list of vectors?

Comment: Not too cumbersome once you wrap it in a function that allows you to search for any given vector. Then your only issue is to think about whether you want to use something like `isTRUE(all.equal())` or `identical` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with objects the `==` operator is not ideal. A slightly simpler approach is:

```
any(sapply(l, identical, y=c(1,2)))
```

The `%in%` operator doesn't work because it is a call to the function `match`. It reads `l` as a vector. In other words, what it's doing is:

```
for(i in 1:length(c(1,2)))
c(1,2)[i]==l[[i]]
```